# Swift notifications with multiple controllers

Tags: ios, swift, notifications

I'm pretty new to iOS development in general and there is one thing I don't understand completely:

I'm writing a swift app with multiple controllers and corresponding views (and a storyboard). I'm using local (iOS8-)notifications with custom actions to get reminders.

Now do I have to add observers to those actions on every controller I have?
I think that there is always only an instance of the "active" controller, is that right? Or does iOS instantiate every controller right from the start?

Greetings (and thanks in advance),
Jascha

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes - you will have to add the observers to every controller that you have because a VC is only instantiated when it's navigated to unless you have state preservation enabled. However, even in that case you would still have to add the obeservers to each VC.

Comment: Thanks. I just added init and deinit-methods to every controller to track their lifecycle. It seems that the FirstController stays alive the whole time while every other controller gets killed when I close their view. But I think that could be dependent of the segue type, all my segues are modals, so I guess it makes sense that the FirstController stays alive.